# How to merge two multidimensional arrays using Laravel/PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, merge

I have two multidimensional arrays.

```
$options = [
    "type" => "identity",
    "document" => [
        "required" => true,
        "allowed_countries" => null,
        "restricted_countries" => null,
        "allowed_types" => null
    ],
    "send_email" => false
    // .... more options
];

$user_options = [
    "type" => "identity",
    "document" => [
        "required" => false
    ],
    "send_email" => false
];
```

I would like to merge them into something like this:

```
 [
          "type" => "identity",
          "document" => [
             "required" => false,
             "allowed_countries" => null,
             "restricted_countries" => null,
             "allowed_types" => null
          ],
          "send_email" => false       
      ];
```

When I am trying to merge them, I am not getting the expected results. For example, using array_merge, I get the following.

```
[
          "type" => "identity",
          "document" => [
             "required" => false,             
          ],
          "send_email" => false       
      ];
```

It removes these keys:

```
 "allowed_countries" => null,
     "restricted_countries" => null,
     "allowed_types" => null
```

**array_merge_recursive** returns the **required** keys combined in one array:

```
"document" => array:4 [▼
    "required" => array:2 [▼
      0 => true
      1 => false
    ]
```

I also tried collections and the merge method in Laravel, but I didn't get the expected results and I don't want that. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP's `array_replace_recursive()` function to merge the arrays. This function replaces the values in the first array with those in the following arrays with the same keys. Their values will be left as is for keys that exist in the first array but not in the following arrays.

```
$options = [
    "type" => "identity",
    "document" => [
        "required" => true,
        "allowed_countries" => null,
        "restricted_countries" => null,
        "allowed_types" => null
    ],
    "send_email" => false
    // .... more options       
];

$user_options = [
    "type" => "identity",
    "document" => [
        "required" => false
    ],
    "send_email" => false       
];

$mergedOptions = array_replace_recursive($options, $user_options);

print_r($mergedOptions);
```

Comment: this is very close for what I was expecting but it doesn't keep the order of the replacement array